# Finding the convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence $a_n = \sqrt[n]{(3^n+5^n)}$ is convergent?

Tried to resolve applying the the limit $n\to\infty$ but couldn't figure out how to finish it, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: $5^n<3^n+5^n<2\cdot 5^n$. Use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: this is the square root of something to the power of $1/n$? are you sure you typed this correctly?

Comment: The (1/n) is the index of the n-root

Comment: So do you mean $a_n = \sqrt[n]{(3^n+5^n)}$?

Comment: @FPE yes, exactly

Comment: @DavidMitra, I got the idea, but, there is any reason for 2*5^n or can be any constant?

Comment: It's simplest to use $3^n+5^n< 5^n+5^n=2\cdot 5^n$, $n>0$.

Comment: The upper bound has to be something that converges to the same limit as the lower bound, for the squeeze theorem to be useful. It could have been $3\cdot 5^n$, for example.

Comment: There is no problem using those in the squeeze theorem without the n-square?

Comment: The inequality carries over to the "n-square"; $(5^n)^{1/n}< a_n < 2^{1/n} (5^n)^{1/n}$, or $5< a_n<2^{1/n}\cdot 5$. Note $2^{1/n}\rightarrow1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get out the term with maximal absolute value

$(3^n + 5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = [5^n((\frac{3}{5})^n +1)]^{\frac{1}{n}} =5((\frac{3}{5})^n +1)^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 5(0+1)^0 = 5$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

$$ a _n =e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln( 3^n+5^n )}= e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(5^n(1+(3/5)^n) )}= e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(5^n) +\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+(3/5)^n) ) }  $$

$$ \sim {5}\,e^{\frac{1}{n} ( 3/5)^n } \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} {5}.  $$

**Note:** we used the Taylor series

> $$ \ln(1+t) = t+O(t^2) $$

Comment: I think you made a couple of mistakes or the post has been amended in between. There is no $\frac{1}{2}$ and the equivalent is wrong.

Comment: @MattB.: It is not my fault. The post has been edited. Check the last edit on it and you will see that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @MattB.: It is fixed.