# Limit of $(1+ x/n)^n$ when $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Does anyone know the exact proof of this limit result?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

Comment: Depends on the definition of $e^x$...

Comment: have you tried to explicit the power and take the limit? It converge to the taylor series.

Comment: I tried by taking log of both sides, but I don't know what to do after this step. Thought of using L'Hopital's rule. But that ain't helping.

Comment: You can use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882659/finding-the-convergence/882680#882680).

Comment: Using L'Hopital on the log you get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(1+\frac{x}{n})}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+x}\frac{-x}{n^2}(- n^2)=x$$

Comment: To cover the complex case, and avoid the log function see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/if-z-n-to-z-then-1z-n-nn-to-ez

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A short proof:

$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^{n\log\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)}$

Since $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ when $x \to 0$, we have $n\log(1 + \frac{x}{n}) = x + O(\frac{x^2}{n})$ when $n\to +\infty$

Comment: neat, really good

Comment: Or just use the derivate of $\log$ to evaluate $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+xy)}{y}$, then let $y=1/n$ to get the limit of $n\log(1+x/n)$...

Comment: Even more elementary would be to use the basic inequality $\frac{x/n}{1+x/n}\le \log(1+x/n)\le x/n$.  Then a straightforward application of the squeeze theorem does the trick.

Comment: In this case, why does writing $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=10^{n\log_{\, 10} \, \, (1+\frac{x}{n})}$    not show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=10^x$?

Comment: @Rasputin because the Taylor expansion of $\log_{10} (1+x)$ is different

Comment: What is $O(x^2)$?

Comment: Okay. But what's log?

Answer (score 52):

$$e^{\ln{(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n} }=e^{n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}$$

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n
=\lim_{n \to +\infty} e^{n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})} \\ 
=e^{\lim_{n \to +\infty} n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}
=e^{\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{ \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Apply L'Hopital's Rule:

$$=e^{\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{(\frac{-x}{n^2})\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}}
=e^{\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}
=e^x$$

Therefore, $$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \to e^x$$

Comment: First: Is the first result in the fourth row by L'Hopital's rule? Second, isn't a limit missing in the second result of the fourth row? $exp(x/(1+x/n))$ should be $exp\{lim[x/(1+x/n)]\}$

Comment: You are correct! I edited it to account for the missing limit. Also, you are correct in that one of the steps is using L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Should I have permission to apply L' Hospital  as  it is n  tends to infinity not x ,I mean it is kind of discrite case not continuous.

Comment: I understand everything except the part $\dfrac{-x}{n^{2}}$. Where does this come from? Isn't the derivative of $\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}$ only?

Comment: you're differentiating with respect to x, not n, my man. The variable in the limit is N not x.

Comment: When applying L'Hopital's Rule, you use quotient rule, yes?

Answer (score 34):

You can use the binomial series expansion. For example:

$$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n =1+ \frac{n}{1!}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^3+\cdots $$

$$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n =1+ \frac{n}{n}x+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3}\frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$$

As $n \to \infty$ the coefficients in $n$ all tend to $1$. Hence:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots $$
You'll recognise this last power series as the Taylor series for $\mathrm{e}^x$.

Comment: what if there are infinite terms and then you cannot exchange the sum and limit if n is non integer

Comment: it's not easy to make this argument rigorous. This answer would be better if it pointed out that fact

Comment: a rigorous version of this argument uses the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series)

Comment: rigorous version: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898375/445105

Comment: @happymath $n$ is Never Non Ninteger :-)