# $e^x$ as a limit proof

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

So I am currently going over some old calculus concepts and ran cross the exponential function expressed as a limit:

$$e^x = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\!1+\frac{x}{n}\!\right)^n $$

Where exactly does this come from? How can we show that this is true?

Additionally, I have also seen this:

$$e^x = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0}(1+xn)^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

How can we show that this is true?

Comment: $n$ as a natural number cannot converge to $0$. About the second limit.

Comment: @SachpazisStelios it's just a dummy variable, it doesn't need to be an integer

Comment: How do you define $e^x$?

Comment: Nice question, but already addressed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/882741/152225).