# Determining the convergence and divergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

So I have a problem of

$$a_n = \left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^n$$

I need to determine whether it is diverging or converging and find the limit if it is converging I found an answer on symbol lab of $e^2$ but I do not know how they got that type of answer

Comment: $e^x = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n $

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed $e^2$, because of the well-known result that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\dfrac xn)^n=e^x$.

Probably my favorite proof of this uses a single interval Riemann sum, coupled with the sandwich or squeeze theorem for limits.

I will try to recreate it if you like.

To wit, define $\ln x:=\int_1^x\dfrac1t\operatorname{dt}$. Then by doing an upper and lower Riemann sum (one subinterval) we get:  $$\dfrac xn\le\ln (1+\dfrac xn)\le\dfrac n{n+x}\cdot\dfrac xn$$.
Now take $e$ of everything,  raise everything to the $n$th power, and take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you know the series converges, that is actually one of the definitions of $e^2.$ Here is another way.

Consider $\ln(a_n)=n\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right).$
Now we look at the form
$$\frac{\ln(1+2/n)}{1/n}=\ln(a_n).$$
We see that 
$$\frac{(\ln(1+2/n))'}{(1/n)}=\frac{\frac{1}{1+2/n}}{-1/n^2}\cdot\frac{-2}{n^2}=\frac{2}{1+2/n}\to 2.$$
So by L'Hopital's 
$$\ln(a_n)\to 2.$$
By continuity 
$$e^{\ln(a_n)}=a_n\to e^2.$$