# Stuck in the proof of $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \to e^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, proof-explanation

I toke this proof from [Limit of $(1+ x/n)^n$ when $n$ tends to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882741/limit-of-1-x-nn-when-n-tends-to-infinity/882763#882763) and there is a step that I don't understand.

Why can we have the pink equality??

$$e^{\ln{(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n} }=e^{n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}$$

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} e^{n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})} \\ =e^{\lim_{n \to +\infty} n \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}=e^{\lim_{ \to +\infty}\frac{ \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}} \\ \color{fuchsia}=e^{\lim_{ \to +\infty}\frac{(\frac{-x}{n^2})\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}}=e^{\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}=e^x$$

Therefore, $$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \to e^x$$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule (w.r.t. $n$), I reckon.

Comment: Also, you are missing a $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in the equality after that.

Comment: yes, is missing @ClementC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is L'Hopital's rule (w.r.t. $n$): letting 
$f(n) = \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})$, $g(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{-x}{n^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
as stated.

---

If you ask me, though, this is an overcomplicated proof. Better to immediately recognize that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})-\ln(1+0)}{\frac{1}{n}-0}
= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+tx)-\ln(1+0)}{t-0}
= \frac{x}{1+x\cdot 0}
$$
by spotting the derivative of $t\mapsto \ln(1+xt)$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Don't you have to justify the use of L'Hôpital's rule in this *sequence* context? In general I don't think it's true that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}$$ For example, consider $f(n):=\sin(2\pi n)$ and $g(n):=n$.

Comment: @NeedForHelp Not sure what you mean. L'Hopital's rule states that (under some mild assumptions) **if** the limit of $\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists, so does that of $\frac{f}{g}$, and they are equal. The "sequence" part is irrelevant here.

Comment: Isn't L'Hôpital's rule for limit of functions, not sequences? In the example I gave, $f'(n)=2\pi\cos(2\pi n)=2\pi$ and $g'(n)=1$ so you seem to claim that $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi}{1}=2\pi$$

Comment: @NeedForHelp Replace $\frac{1}{n}$ by $x$ in the OP's limit and you'll see why it works. The limit exists when $x\to 0$, so in particular it exists along the particular sequence $(1/n)_n$ which also goes to 0. Regarding your counterexample, it is *not* an actual counterexample. The limit $f'(n)/g'(n)$ here does not exist! (the numerator does not converge to $2\pi$, $2\pi\cos (2\pi n)$ keeps oscillating when $n\to\infty$).

Comment: This little justification you just gave is what I thought was missing. I don't see how $\cos(2\pi n)$ keeps oscillating when $n\to\infty$ since it is constant.

Comment: @NeedForHelp Oh, my bad. I must have fried my last remaining neurons before that last comment. But basically, you cannot apply [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to your counterexample (check the condition that ($f\to \pm\infty$ and $g\to \pm\infty$) (or $f\to 0$ and $g\to 0$). So, in short: the "sequentialization" of the limit is irrelevant to using L'Hopital's rule here, since you want to apply it to the continuous "version" (and if the limit exists when $x\to 0$, it exists when you take a particular sequence $x_n\to0$, here $(1/n)_n$.)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the generalization of the well known limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e\;\;\;\text{whenever the sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ fulfills}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$

then you can do as follows (beside l'Hospital, as shown in what you wrote):

$$\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac1{\frac nx}\right)^{n/x}\right]^x\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^x$$

using the sequence $\;a_n:=\cfrac nx\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;,\;\;x>0\;$

For $\;x<0\;$ it is very similar. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

From
$\ln(1+z)
=\int_0^z \frac{dt}{1+t}
$
and,
for $t > 0$
we have
$1-t
\lt \frac1{1+t}
\lt 1
$
we have
$\ln(1+z)
\gt \int_0^z (1-t) dt
=z-\frac{z^2}{2}
$
and
$\ln(1+z)
\lt \int_0^z (1) dt
=z
$.

Putting
$z = \frac{x}{n}$,
we get
$\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}
\lt \ln(1+\frac{x}{n})
\lt\frac{x}{n}
$
so that
$x-\frac{x^2}{2n}
\lt n\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})
\lt x
$.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital's rule has been applied: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Answer (score 1):

*Just another way to show it.*

Consider 
$$A_n=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(A_n)=n \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$$ Now, since $n$ is large, by Taylor $$\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$\log(A_n)={x}-\frac{x^2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Taylor again $$A_n=e^{\log(A_n)}=e^x-\frac{e^x x^2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.