# How to determine if this complex sequence converges or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I don't know how to start to determine whether $(1+i/n)^n$ is convergent as $n$ tends to infinity. I feel like I will have to use Archimedes's property but the use of $i$ is making it hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x\tag{1}$$

How to apply this to your problem?

You have $a_n= \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n$.

> Using  $(1)$ we conclude that sequence converges to $e^i$.

Source( In case you want to read more about this limit) [Limit of $(1+ x/n)^n$ when $n$ tends to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882741/limit-of-1-x-nn-when-n-tends-to-infinity)

Comment: When i first saw your comment, I thought that the $(1+i/n)^n = e^i$, but that doesn't work as $i=e^i\pi/2$. So I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @M.Calculator I don't understand your above comment. What is the problem if $i=e^{i\pi/2}$? The limit  of $(1+i/n)^n$ when n tends to infinity is is $e^i$

Comment: I am not sure what my original equation converges to, and from your first comment, I replaced the $x$ with an $i$ to get $e^i$ but that isn't what the equation converges to. I am just incredibly stuck to how to use your hint or how to progress on this question. Sorry for the poor explanation on my previous comment.

Comment: @M.Calculator See the edited post

Answer (score 0):

This is a little  complicated but I will  try and make everything clear  without  doing  the i - substitution. In the first  place equate ur function to y and find ln of both sidkmes. Apply  ln rules at the RHS to obtain a rational  function . Then use L'hopital's rule at the rig
ht  hand side and find the limit at the RHS.after everything  u find natural exponent at both  sides and now ur limit is determined.