# A question regarding the prime-number theorem

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, eulers-number-e

If you consider the fact that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=e$$
Where $e$ is Euler's number. Now, the prime number theorem states that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {\pi(x)\over x / \ln{x}}=1$$
Where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function. Now, think about, if we say that:
$$\pi(x)={x\over \log_{c_x}{x}}$$
Where $c_x$ is some constant at the $x$th order, and the prime-number theorem is equivalent to saying:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} c_x=e$$
Now, consider that to calculate $c_x$ based on $\pi(x)$ is quite easy:
$$c_x=\sqrt[{x\over \pi(x)}]{x}=x^{\pi(x)\over x}=(\sqrt[x]{x})^{\pi(x)}$$
Now, the prime-number theorem can be written as:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt[x]{x})^{\pi(x)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n$$
We can see that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+{1\over n}$, since both $\rightarrow 1$, and considering that both the powers diverge, this may be a stupid question, but, is this enough to be a proof of the prime-number theorem? If not, what more do you need here, for this to be a proof of it?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Here's a short proof that $lim_{x\to\infty} (1 + {1\over x})^x=e$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882741/limit-of-1-x-nn-when-n-tends-to-infinity

Comment: Your proof contains the asumtion that $\pi(x)$ has this asymptotic behaviour. Just that this does not lead to a contradiction, does not prove that $\pi(x)$ actually behaves asymptotically this way.

Comment: @Peter My proof only assumes that $\pi(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I have edited my question.

Comment: Where have you used that $\pi(x)$ counts the prime numbers $\leq x\>$?

Comment: @Tots As $n \to \infty$, $2n \to \infty$, but $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{2n} \to e^2 \neq e$ as $n \to \infty$. Similarly, $n^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, but $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^n} = \infty \neq e$$ So, as Peter says, not showing a contradiction is not the same as a proof. You have not shown anything about the asymptotic nature of $\pi(x)$.

Comment: Here's another issue: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt[x]{x}}{1+\dfrac{1}{x}} = 1$$ but $$e = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x \neq \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt[x]{x}\right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last paragraph you seem to be using the following assertion: if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)= \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)} = e$. This is not true. Consider for example
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( 1+\tfrac1x \big)^{\sqrt x} &= 1 \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( 1+\tfrac1x \big)^{x/2} &= \sqrt e \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( 1+\tfrac1x \big)^{x} &= e \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( 1+\tfrac1x \big)^{3x} &= e^3 \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( 1+\tfrac1x \big)^{x^2} &= \infty
\end{align*}
all of which can be proved by taking logarithms and using $0\times\infty$ indeterminate form techniques. (Indeed, such an $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is a $1^\infty$ indeterminate form; if the answer always equaled $e$, then it wouldn't be called an indeterminate form at all!)

Comment: If we compare $(1+{1\over x})^x$ with $f(x)^{g(x)}$, I was thinking about if you proved, that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$, but $f(x)$ tends to $1$ more slowly than $1 + {1\over x}$, then $g(x)$'s growth rate difference with $x$ has to be similar to the difference of the growth rate between $f(x)$ and $1 + {1\over x}$, so that maybe, $lim_{x\to\infty} (1 + {1\over x})^x=lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)^{g(n)}$

Comment: The correct way to resolve this "maybe" is to carry out the indeterminate-form process to find out what the answer is. In its inverse form as you proposed to use it, it can't tell the difference between $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ and $\pi(x) \sim x/(\log x)^{100}$ and even $\pi(x) \sim x(\log x)^{100}$.