# How to show that $\lim_{m\to \infty} (1+x/m)^m \geq e_n(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here $e_n(x)$ is $n$-th partial sum of the exponential series. I was in the proof for $(1+x/n)^n\to e^x$ as $n\to \infty$. It is shown that $e_n(x)\geq (1+x/n)^n$ using binomial theorem.

According to the instruction I have to prove $\lim_{m\to \infty} (1+x/m)^m \geq e_n(x)$. If we prove this we have $e^x\geq\lim_{m\to \infty} (1+x/m)^m \geq e_n(x)$. So $(1+x/n)^n\to e^x$. But I stuck there. Please anyone help, only using sequence and series techniques.

Comment: In you second paragraph, some of the powers $n$ should be $m$.

Comment: oops edited now.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2

Comment: yeah perfect. Thanks.

Comment: This proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882741/limit-of-1-x-nn-when-n-tends-to-infinity may give you the answer to your question too.